# Getting an Error Meassage "System.IO.FileFormatException: Compressed part has inconsistent data length" calling XmlDocument.Load()

Tags: asp.net, openxml, openxml-sdk

I'm new to OpenXML,here i'm trying to export chart data to powerpoint.Here in the code i trying to save it as excel file and then to powerpoint,while trying click on the export button it showing me an error message(Written as aheading).here i'm  my code.

```
    protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            // Open an existing Presentation

            PresentationDocument oPDoc = PresentationDocument.Open(@"D:\Chart.pptx", true);

            PresentationPart oPPart = oPDoc.PresentationPart;

            // Get the ReleationshipId of the first Slide

            SlideId slideId = oPPart.Presentation.SlideIdList.GetFirstChild<SlideId>();

            string relId = slideId.RelationshipId;

            // Get the slide part by the relationship ID.

            SlidePart slidePart = (SlidePart)oPPart.GetPartById(relId);

            // Add a new chart part

            ChartPart chPrt = slidePart.AddNewPart<ChartPart>();

            XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();

            String strFileName = "D:\\chart1.xml";

            xDoc.Load(strFileName);

            StreamWriter objDocMainWrt = new StreamWriter(chPrt.GetStream(FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write));

            xDoc.Save(objDocMainWrt);

            // Add the data Sheet for the Chart

            ExtendedPart objEmbPart = chPrt.AddExtendedPart("http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/package", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", ".xlsx");

            strFileName = "D:\\chartData.xlsx";

            FileStream partStream = new FileStream(strFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

            objEmbPart.FeedData(partStream);

            // Change the Data releation ID used in Chart.xml

            // Elemenet changed : c:externalData

            string relChtDataID = chPrt.GetIdOfPart(objEmbPart);

            XmlNamespaceManager nsManager1 = new XmlNamespaceManager(xDoc.NameTable);

            XmlNamespaceManager nsManagerDraw = new XmlNamespaceManager(xDoc.NameTable);

            //nsManager1.AddNamespace("c", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart");

            nsManagerDraw.AddNamespace("d", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart");

            //XmlNodeList nodeTest = xDoc.SelectNodes("//c:externalData", nsManager1);
            XmlNodeList nodeTest = xDoc.SelectNodes("//d:chart1", nsManagerDraw);

            foreach (XmlNode node in nodeTest)
            {

                node.Attributes["r:id"].Value = relChtDataID;

            }

            // Save changes back to Chart.xml

            xDoc.Save(chPrt.GetStream(FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write));

            // Get the SlidePart Stream

            const string presentationmlNamespace = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main";

            NameTable nt = new NameTable();

            XmlNamespaceManager nsManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(nt);

            nsManager.AddNamespace("p", presentationmlNamespace);

            XmlDocument presXML = new XmlDocument(nt);

            presXML.Load(slidePart.GetStream());



            // Get the spTree Element in SlidePart

            XmlNode nodeTree = presXML.SelectSingleNode("//p:spTree", nsManager);

            string rid = slidePart.GetIdOfPart(chPrt).ToString();

            // Generate the Graphic Element for the Chart

            XmlNode childNode = GenerateNode(rid);

            //Append the Graphic Element to spTree Element in SlidePart

            nodeTree.AppendChild(presXML.ImportNode(childNode, true));

            Stream o = slidePart.GetStream();

            presXML.Save(o);

            oPDoc.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception msg)
        {
            Response.Write(msg.ToString());
        }
    }
private XmlNode GenerateNode(String rId)
    {

        XmlDocument xwb = new XmlDocument();

        xwb.AppendChild(xwb.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "yes"));

        XmlNamespaceManager xmlns = new XmlNamespaceManager(xwb.NameTable);

        xmlns.AddNamespace("p", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main");

        xmlns.AddNamespace("r", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships");

        xmlns.AddNamespace("a", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main");

        XmlElement eleGraphic = xwb.CreateElement("p:graphicFrame", xmlns.LookupNamespace("p"));

        xwb.AppendChild(eleGraphic);

        XmlElement eleGrpFrm = xwb.CreateElement("p:nvGraphicFramePr", xmlns.LookupNamespace("p"));

        eleGraphic.AppendChild(eleGrpFrm);

        XmlElement elePpr = xwb.CreateElement("p:cNvPr", xmlns.LookupNamespace("p"));

        eleGrpFrm.AppendChild(elePpr);

        XmlAttribute attrRid = xwb.CreateAttribute("id");

        attrRid.Value = "4";

        elePpr.SetAttributeNode(attrRid);

        XmlAttribute attrName = xwb.CreateAttribute("name");

        attrName.Value = "Chart 2";

        elePpr.SetAttributeNode(attrName);

        XmlElement elecNvGraphicFramePr = xwb.CreateElement("p:cNvGraphicFramePr", xmlns.LookupNamespace("p"));

        eleGrpFrm.AppendChild(elecNvGraphicFramePr);

        XmlElement elenvPr = xwb.CreateElement("p:nvPr", xmlns.LookupNamespace("p"));

        eleGrpFrm.AppendChild(elenvPr);

        XmlElement elexfrm = xwb.CreateElement("p:xfrm", xmlns.LookupNamespace("p"));

        eleGraphic.AppendChild(elexfrm);

        XmlElement eleoff = xwb.CreateElement("a:off", xmlns.LookupNamespace("a"));

        elexfrm.AppendChild(eleoff);

        XmlAttribute xvalue = xwb.CreateAttribute("x");

        xvalue.Value = "1524000";

        eleoff.SetAttributeNode(xvalue);

        XmlAttribute yvalue = xwb.CreateAttribute("y");

        yvalue.Value = "1397000";

        eleoff.SetAttributeNode(yvalue);

        XmlElement eleext = xwb.CreateElement("a:ext", xmlns.LookupNamespace("a"));

        elexfrm.AppendChild(eleext);

        XmlAttribute cxvalue = xwb.CreateAttribute("cx");

        cxvalue.Value = "6096000";

        eleext.SetAttributeNode(cxvalue);

        XmlAttribute cyvalue = xwb.CreateAttribute("cy");

        cyvalue.Value = "4064000";

        eleext.SetAttributeNode(cyvalue);

        //<c:chart xmlns:c="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" r:id="rId2"/></a:graphicData></a:graphic></p:graphicFrame>

        XmlElement elegraphic = xwb.CreateElement("a:graphic", xmlns.LookupNamespace("a"));

        eleGraphic.AppendChild(elegraphic);

        XmlElement elegraphicData = xwb.CreateElement("a:graphicData", xmlns.LookupNamespace("a"));

        elegraphic.AppendChild(elegraphicData);

        XmlAttribute uri = xwb.CreateAttribute("uri");

        uri.Value = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart";

        elegraphicData.SetAttributeNode(uri);

        XmlElement elechart = xwb.CreateElement("c:chart", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart");

        elegraphicData.AppendChild(elechart);

        XmlAttribute id = xwb.CreateAttribute("r:id", xmlns.LookupNamespace("r"));

        id.Value = rId;

        elechart.SetAttributeNode(id);



        XmlNode ss1 = xwb.SelectSingleNode("//p:graphicFrame", xmlns);

        return ss1;

        //xwb.Save(@"C:\temp\test1.xml");
    }
```

Please let me know where i have done mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below code,before that create empty ppt template and excel with two chart controls.

```
           string paramPresentationPath = @"D:\Chart.pptx";
            string paramWorkbookPath = @"D:\chartData.xlsx";
            object paramMissing = Type.Missing;

            powerpointApplication = new pptNS.Application();

            // Create an instance Excel.          
            excelApplication = new xlNS.Application();

            // Open the Excel workbook containing the worksheet with the chart
            // data.
            excelWorkBook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(paramWorkbookPath,
                            paramMissing, paramMissing, paramMissing,
                            paramMissing, paramMissing, paramMissing,
                            paramMissing, paramMissing, paramMissing,
                            paramMissing, paramMissing, paramMissing,
                            paramMissing, paramMissing);

            // Get the worksheet that contains the chart.
            targetSheet = (xlNS.Worksheet)(excelWorkBook.Worksheets[1]);//here 1 is sheet no.

            // Get the ChartObjects collection for the sheet.
            chartObjects = (xlNS.ChartObjects)(targetSheet.ChartObjects(paramMissing));

            // Get the chart to copy.
            existingChartObject = (xlNS.ChartObject)(chartObjects.Item("Chart Name in Excel"));

            // Create a PowerPoint presentation.
            pptPresentation = powerpointApplication.Presentations.Add(
                                Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue);

            // Add a blank slide to the presentation.
            pptSlide = pptPresentation.Slides.Add(1, pptNS.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutBlank);

            // Copy the chart from the Excel worksheet to the clipboard.
            existingChartObject.Copy();

            // Paste the chart into the PowerPoint presentation.
            shapeRange = pptSlide.Shapes.Paste();

            // Position the chart on the slide.
            shapeRange.Left = 30;
            shapeRange.Top = 100;

            // Width and Height on the Slide.
            shapeRange.Width = 600;
            shapeRange.Height = 400;


            ///<summary>
            ///Second Slide
            ///</summary>

            // Get the worksheet that contains the chart.
            targetSheet = (xlNS.Worksheet)(excelWorkBook.Worksheets[2]);

            // Get the ChartObjects collection for the sheet.
            chartObjects = (xlNS.ChartObjects)(targetSheet.ChartObjects(paramMissing));

            // Get the chart to copy.
            existingChartObject = (xlNS.ChartObject)(chartObjects.Item("Chart Name in excel"));

            //// Create a PowerPoint presentation.
            //pptPresentation = powerpointApplication.Presentations.Add(
            //                    Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue);

            // Add a blank slide to the presentation.
            pptSlide = pptPresentation.Slides.Add(2, pptNS.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutBlank);

            // Copy the chart from the Excel worksheet to the clipboard.
            existingChartObject.Copy();

            // Paste the chart into the PowerPoint presentation.
            shapeRange = pptSlide.Shapes.Paste();

            // Position the chart on the slide.
            shapeRange.Left = 30;
            shapeRange.Top = 100;

            // Width and Height on the Slide.
            shapeRange.Width = 600;
            shapeRange.Height = 400;


            // Save the presentation.
            pptPresentation.SaveAs(paramPresentationPath,
                            pptNS.PpSaveAsFileType.ppSaveAsOpenXMLPresentation,
                            Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue);

            //pptPresentation.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception msg)
        {
            Response.Write(msg.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            shapeRange = null;
            pptSlide = null;

            object paramMissing = Type.Missing;

            // Close and release the Presentation object.
            if (pptPresentation != null)
            {
                pptPresentation.Close();
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(pptPresentation);
                //Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pptPresentation.Slides);
                pptPresentation = null;
            }

            // Quit PowerPoint and release the ApplicationClass object.
            if (powerpointApplication != null)
            {
                powerpointApplication.Quit();
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(powerpointApplication);
                powerpointApplication = null;
            }

            // Release the Excel objects.
            targetSheet = null;
            chartObjects = null;
            existingChartObject = null;

            //Close and release the Excel Workbook object.
            if (excelWorkBook != null)
            {
                excelWorkBook.Close(false, paramMissing, paramMissing);
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excelWorkBook);
                excelWorkBook = null;
            }

            // Quit Excel and release the ApplicationClass object.
            if (excelApplication != null)
            {
                excelApplication.Quit();
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excelApplication);
                excelApplication = null;

                //System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelApplication);
            }

            ////releaseObject(ref excelApplication);

            ////releaseObject(ref powerpointApplication);

            System.Diagnostics.Process[] excelprc = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL");
            if (excelprc.Length == 1)
            {
                excelprc[0].Kill();
            }

            System.Diagnostics.Process[] ppprc = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("POWERPNT");
            if (ppprc.Length == 1)
            {
                ppprc[0].Kill();
            }

            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```